# How can I rewrap typeclass instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to represent a concept of an upper bound in my code so I created a discriminated union:

```hs
data UpperBound a = UpperBound a | DoNotCare deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

I then manually derived several useful typeclass instances (for learning purposes):

```hs
instance Functor UpperBound where
    fmap _ DoNotCare = DoNotCare
    fmap f (UpperBound x) = UpperBound $ f x

instance Applicative UpperBound where
    pure = UpperBound
    DoNotCare <*> _ = DoNotCare
    _ <*> DoNotCare = DoNotCare
    (UpperBound f) <*> (UpperBound x) = UpperBound $ f x

instance Foldable UpperBound where
    foldr _ s DoNotCare = s
    foldr f s (UpperBound x) = f x s

instance Traversable UpperBound where
    traverse _ DoNotCare = pure DoNotCare
    traverse f (UpperBound x) = fmap UpperBound $ f x

instance Alternative UpperBound where
    empty = DoNotCare
    DoNotCare <|> x = x
    x <|> DoNotCare = x
    x <|> _ = x

instance Monad UpperBound where
    return = pure
    DoNotCare >>= _ = DoNotCare
    (UpperBound x) >>= f = f x

instance MonadPlus UpperBound where
    mzero = empty
    mplus = (<|>)
```

and a single utility function:

```hs
isWithinBound :: Ord a => a -> UpperBound a -> Bool
isWithinBound _ DoNotCare = True
isWithinBound x (UpperBound b) = x <= b
```

The typeclass instances look almost the same as the ones for `Maybe` (`Just x` -> `UpperBound x`, `Nothing` -> `DoNotCare`) so it seems I am clearly having unnecessary duplication here.

How can I somehow ‘wrap’ a `Maybe` and redirect the typeclass instances implementations to that and still expose the `isWithinBound` function?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question - but can't you just use a `newtype`? Or even a type synonym if your instances are actually identical (as they appear to be).

Comment: Regarding `isWithinBound`, it's trivial to rewrite so it takes a `Maybe a` instead of your custom version.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I mean I want to still expose the cases as `UpperBound/DoNotCare` but internally forward to instance declarations to a `Maybe` implementation. Is that possible?

Comment: "The typeclass instances look almost the same as the ones for Maybe" where does the "almost" part come from?

Comment: @n.m. you can *almost* do a global regex replace of `UpperBound` to `Just` and `DoNotCare` to `None` in all the implementation of typeclass instances and the code will still compile for the `Maybe` type.

Comment: That `Alternative` instance looks sketchy to me. It's supposed to be a monoid for each contained type (with `empty` as the unit and `<|>` as the operation) -- and in particular it's supposed to have `empty <|> x = x <|> empty = x`, which yours does not.

Comment: @DanielWagner you are right. I have changed my code to fix that confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `newtype` and `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, DeriveTraversable #-}
module UpperBound (UpperBound, isWithinBound) where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

newtype UpperBound a = UpperBound { unUpperBound :: Maybe a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Foldable, Traversable, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus)

isWithinBound :: Ord a => a -> UpperBound a -> Bool
isWithinBound x = maybe True ((<=) x) . unUpperBound
```

So all the instances you need are automatically redirected to those of `Maybe` (besides `Traversable` which is derived automatically using the `DeriveTraversable` extension).

Comment: I never realised `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` didn't work for `Traversable` (I've never used it other than for `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`). I'm curious as to why this might be.

Comment: @RobinZogmond If newtype U x = U (T x) and Traversable T, then traverse returns a f (T x) where you need a f (U x). GHC wants a zero-cost coercion between the two, but there isn’t one. You’d need to fmap U, and GHC won’t do that by itself. Now, since Functor f, morally f should always be type role f representational, and there *should* be a coercion available, but 1) Traversable doesn’t have that constraint on it 2) There are some “broken” but useful functors breaking this rule 3) GND probably can’t use the information even if it’s given and 4) such constraints are a very new GHC extension.